# JPA: Specification does not work on Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a specification that should get all entries with a datetime greater that the current:

```
    public static Specification<Booking> currentBookings() {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            LocalDateTime dateTime =
                    LocalDateTime.now().withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("fromTime"), dateTime);
        };
    }
```

The field fromTime is a timestamp within the databases H2 (local) Postgres (test).
The actual call is combined with a user id:

`return bookingRepository.findAll(forUser(userId).and(currentBookings()));`

The resulting query is:

```
select b1_0.id,b1_0.desk_id,b1_0.from_time,b1_0.until_time,b1_0.user_id from booking b1_0 where b1_0.user_id=1 and b1_0.from_time>='2023-11-23 00:00:00'
```

This works perfectly fine for H2 database on the local development machine but does not return a result if executed on the postgres console although there should be some results. If I modify the query to (simplified)

I will get the expected results.
What am I doing wrong there? Shouldn't JPA take care of such conversions from LocalDateTime to Timestamp in the background? You do not have to set the database dialect explicitly in the properties as it should be gained automatically...
I can easily transform the repository and create a custom query but I wonder why the specification is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could arise from the fact that PostgreSQL requires a certain format for the timestamp, and Hibernate/JPA's default conversion may not be adequate for PostgreSQL.
Change your currentBookings method such that LocalDateTime is replaced with Timestamp. In this manner, you deal with the database type that PostgreSQL expects explicitly.
Try this code;

```
public static Specification<Booking> currentBookings() {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Timestamp dateTime = Timestamp.valueOf(
                LocalDateTime.now().withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0)
        );
        return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("fromTime"), dateTime);
    };
}
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Yes that helped. Strange thing is that it seems to work with other queries where I use a local date time e.g. for this one:
    @Query(
            "select booking from Booking booking left join booking.desk desk where desk.id in :deskIds and ((booking.fromTime >= :fromTime and booking.untilTime <= :untilTime) or (booking.fromTime <= :untilTime and :fromTime <= booking.untilTime))")
    List<Booking> getBookingsForDesksForPeriod(List<Long> deskIds, LocalDateTime fromTime, LocalDateTime untilTime);